# iOS 3D Touch programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone

`3D Touch` is introduced in iPhone 6s/iPhone 6s plus,and I am wondering if we could have access to 3D Touch related API and do it programmatically in our app.Does anyone has some ideas?

Comment: Did you look at any of the documentation, articles, or sample code? https://developer.apple.com/ios/3d-touch/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will have access to 3D touch functionality in apps. There will be a new property, `force`, in the `UITouch` class that will hold the strength that a tap event has. 1.0 is defined to be an "average touch".

Source: https://developer.apple.com/ios/3d-touch/

Comment: Thanks for the guide.

Comment: What would be the value for a hard press?

Comment: @HarryNg Probably anything more than 1.0. I'm not sure though. I presume you'd have to do a little bit of testing to find out.

Comment: @ddsnowboard, cool thanks for quick reply. I think we all need to wait for the device launch.

Comment: I made a force touch gesture recognizer that be may of interest: https://github.com/foggzilla/UIContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer. A UItouch force of 1.0 is considered a standard press, with > 1.0 considered more forceful.

Answer (score 2):

I am sharing the source code for pressing on app icon populate 4 item in list

**Step 1**:- Import class in `appDelegate.m`

```
import sys/utsname.h
```

**Step 2**:-

```
#pragma MARK for Get Machine Name

-  (NSString *) machineName {
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);
    return [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if([[self machineName] isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,2"]|| [[self machineName] isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,1"]) {
        [self addEventsFor3DTouchEvents];
    }
    return YES;
}


#pragma MARK for Adding Action for Three D Touch Eventes

- (void) addEventsFor3DTouchEvents {
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9.0) {
        UIApplicationShortcutItem *item1 = [[UIApplicationShortcutItem alloc] initWithType:@"dynamic1" localizedTitle:TITLE_NAME_1 localizedSubtitle:@"" icon:[UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithTemplateImageName:TITLE_IMAGE_NAME_1] userInfo:nil];

        UIApplicationShortcutItem *item2 = [[UIApplicationShortcutItem alloc] initWithType:@"dynamic1" localizedTitle:TITLE_NAME_2 localizedSubtitle:@"" icon:[UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithTemplateImageName:TITLE_IMAGE_NAME_2] userInfo:nil];

        UIApplicationShortcutItem *item3 = [[UIApplicationShortcutItem alloc] initWithType:@"dynamic1" localizedTitle:TITLE_NAME_3 localizedSubtitle:@"" icon:[UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithTemplateImageName:TITLE_IMAGE_NAME_3] userInfo:nil];

        UIApplicationShortcutItem *item4 = [[UIApplicationShortcutItem alloc] initWithType:@"dynamic1" localizedTitle:TITLE_NAME_4 localizedSubtitle:@"" icon:[UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithTemplateImageName:TITLE_IMAGE_NAME_4] userInfo:nil];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setShortcutItems: @[ item1, item2, item3, item4 ]];
    }
}


#pragma mark - 3DTouch Delegate Methods

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performActionForShortcutItem:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)shortcutItem completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler {
    [self moveThrough3DTouch:shortcutItem];
}

#pragma MARK for Handling Action for Three D Touch Events

- (void)moveThrough3DTouch:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)temp {

    if ([temp.localizedTitle isEqualToString:TITLE_NAME_1])  {

            [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
    } else if([temp.localizedTitle isEqualToString:TITLE_NAME_2]) {

            [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
    } else if([temp.localizedTitle isEqualToString:TITLE_NAME_3]) {

            [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
    } else if([temp.localizedTitle isEqualToString:TITLE_NAME_4]) {

            [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
    }
}
```

I am using Tab Bar controller in my app, If want to move in view controlled:

```
- (void) moveToControllerScene {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard              = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:STORY_BOARD_IDENTIFIER bundle:nil];
        YOUR_CONTROLLER_OBJECT *obj           = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_CONTROLLER_OBJECT"];
        [navController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
}
```